# How do I clear the current session when logging out using devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

So my application is using Devise to manage authentication.  I recently added a logout button to the app and it seemed to work fine redirecting to the login screen.  However today I was running some tests on the login screen and found that I was still logged into the app even after using the logout routine.

In my initializer I have:

```
config.sign_out_via = :delete
```

My logout link looks like this:

```
<%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

I have a check on ApplicationController to see if the user is required to be logged in:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_filter :require_login
   ...
   def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
       login_path           # displays login page
   end

   def require_login
       redirect_to login_url unless current_user && user_signed_in?
   end
```

For some reason the user_signed_in? check is still returning true even after the clicking the logout link.  So I can still go back into the application without having to re-enter my credentials.  This obviously shouldn't be the case.

UPDATE:

Here is the output from the server log:

Started DELETE "/users/sign_out" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 13:05:07 +1000
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"Na06x5aAzq/XVhJKrxKEIoh/Bly53fIAq0KEQTG hmM="}

**Can't verify CSRF token authenticity**

UPDATE 2:

I just noticed now that when I try to log into the app using different login details it isn't working.  Since I'm not being logged out it looks like it's skipping the login routine and redirecting me back in.  I know that this was working previously so something has changed since to break this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after hours spent trying to figure this out I found two issues.

The first problem was this line in ApplicationController.rb:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```

I added this some time ago to hide errors if a user tried to log out twice.  However, this hid the problem I was experiencing.

The actual issue is an InvalidAuthenticityToken error.  It was stopping logging out and also (as I found later) logging in.

To fix the problem I have added the following line (and this is possibly not the correct solution) to ApplicationController.rb:

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
```

For some reason I've been experiencing this problem elsewhere in the application and to be honest (I'm new to rails) I've no idea why this error has suddenly started causing me so many headaches.